# Using session tokens instead of REST API key with Parse REST API

Tags: rest, parse-server

I'm using the Parse REST API in my flutter app and I've setup a REST API key in the index.js and it all works. However, I want to make use of session tokens as the security measure rather than REST key as I only want logged in users to be able to interact with the server. Is there a way to use session tokens instead of REST API key or another approach which delivers the intended usage?

Comment: store the parse session on the client per norms on flutter-client. use http headers to submit session to server-side. Use API for 'session-to-User' per the parse/rest/docs ...  -H "X-Parse-Session-Token: ${mySessionID}\
  https://YOUR.PARSE-SERVER.HERE/parse/users/me

Comment: can this act as a replacement of sorts for the REST API key i.e. instead of using the REST key can I use this method to make sure only authenticated users are using the app?

Comment: API key is req'd with REST . the parse.rest.docs are pretty clear on that one.